# Xcode 6.2: no iOS simulators available?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, swift

I am running a Mac 10.10.3. I am working on a iOS project.

I got an error when using Xcode 6.3 that didn't appear in Xcode 6.2. The video I was listening to was also using Xcode 6.2.

When I got it, there were no simulators. I went to Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads. There were two downloads: an iOS 8.1 and 7.1 simulator. But I can't run my program. There are no actual virtual devices or anything.

In Xcode 6.3, there were a bunch of devices. iPhone 4, 4s, 5, 5s, etc. Nothing's there except iOS device in Xcode 6.2. How do I make them appear?

To be clear: I want **the devices** to run my program.

Comment: What's wrong with using the latest version of Xcode?

Comment: According to WikiPedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#2.x_series it's XCode 3.1that brought iOS (Simulator) to developers. Plus, XCode 3's release was previous to iOS, so XCode 2 shouldn't have iOS Simulator.

Comment: Why are you using 10.3 and XCode 3?? There are additional downloads [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) but you really shouldn't be using software from over 12 years ago... It's unsafe and doesn't get any updates anymore

Comment: Xcode 2 is absurdly old, and no longer supported. There was a huge rewrite of Xcode with Xcode 4.0, and then another large-scale rewrite with Xcode 6. Using anything other than the latest tools is silly. As @Larme points out, the iOS simulator was added in Xcode 3.1, so it won't be available in any version of Xcode prior to that, and if I remember correctly, Apple offered different builds of Xcode with and without the iOS SDK at that point.

Comment: I guess you have installed all the available versions of XCode on your system. Anyways, each XCode require simulators to be downloaded, it can't use simulators of other XCode that you might have installed. Suggestion. Keep only the latest version of XCode to eliminate confusion.

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant to say Xcode 6.2, not 2.

Comment: Did you upgrade it using the DMG or through the app store?

Comment: @chedabob the DMG through developer.apple.com

Comment: In my experience, installing via the DMG wipes out the simulators and the command line tools and they have to be reinstalled. I do rename my old Xcode installation so I can run two side-by-side, so that could be a factor in it.

Comment: @chedabob I have 6.2 and 6.3 running side-by-side. Is there any way to get the devices on 6.2?

Comment: To my knowledge no. You have to reinstall them. You may also have to delete them from Organizer and re-add them if they won't launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in Xcode 6.3 (**SIX.THREE**, please update the title of your question) you have no Simulator available you just need to:

1. Open **Xcode** > **Preferences** > **Downloads**
2. Click the **Download** button next to an **iOS Simulator**
3. Wait for the download to complete
4. Now you can select the Simulator as you did in the previous version

[image: Xcode > Preferences > Downloads]

Hope this helps.

Comment: You mean you need the iOS 6 Simulator? I am afraid it is no longer available. However please consider that most of the App Store active users are running iOS 8 or 7.

Comment: I want the virtual devices to run my app (iPhone 4, 4s, 5, 5s).

Comment: They will appear as soon as you download at least one simulator. Just follow the steps detailed in my answer.

Comment: Ok one question. In Xcode select the root of your project, then select your target. What value can you see in the **Deployment Target** field?

Comment: iOS deployment target: iOS 8.3. I'll send some screenshots to make stuff clearer in a few minutes.

Comment: Ok, that means your app will run only on iOS 8.3 (and later). Just download the iOS 8.3 Simulator.

Comment: Ok, let's try to change the **Deployment Target** to **iOS 8.2**

Answer (score 2):

That's correct. Xcode did not add support for iOS development until Xcode 3.1.

Unless you are supporting VERY old iOS hardware and OS versions, there is no good reason to deal with such old versions of Xcode, and many good reasons not to. Xcode 3.1, the first version of Xcode to support iOS development, is from 2008.

Comment: I'm sorry everyone, this is Xcode 6.2, not 2. I made a mistake.

Comment: Oh! Well that's an IDE of a different color!